# Modifying values in list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list in the form of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)]

`test = [(5, 3.7357663e-01), (10, 1.2537051e-01), (15, 6.7936250e-02)]`

I am trying to do a calculation on y values: nature log(y)

which results in

`test = [(5, -0.9846321281171939), (10, -2.076481845903636), (15, -2.6891855135340066)]`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np

test1 = [(x, np.log(y)) for x, y in test]
```